# Why is Google Chrome Canary shortened to "chromesxs"?

Tags: google-chrome

Download page: `http://tools.google.com/dlpage/chromesxs`

The path to the  data folder for chrome on Windows contains `...\Google\Chrome SxS\...`

What does sxs mean?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

SxS means [Side-by-side](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Side-by-side_assembly) and probably refers to the fact that you can install and run Canary and Chrome stable on the same computer at the same time.